# is there a way to get the elite and rare status of a creature (WoW Classic)?

Tags: battlenet-api

I am working on an Addon and need a list of every Elite and Rare in the game.
The creature method returns its type and name but I don't see a status if it is an elite or not.
Anyone know if it is possible to get that info via an api?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. You can use the creature API from the official documentation for the API.

https://develop.battle.net/documentation/world-of-warcraft-classic/game-data-apis

Comment: but it doesnt give me any status if it is an elite or not.